# Razor view not working with AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developing a .NEt MVC application, have a form with razor view along with AngularJS inputs but ng_change is not working. Its working fine with normal HTML inputs. Below is the syntax

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.R10Length, new { @class="form-control fcus", step="any", min="1", ng_model= "conf.amr10length", ng_change= "fr15length()", ng_value= "@Request['r10length']" })
```

Working fine for

```
<input type="number" ng-model="conf.amr10length" step="any" min="1" maxlength="5" name="r10length" id="r10length" class="form-control fcus" placeholder="R10 Length" ng-change="fr15length()" value="@Request["r10length"]" required />
```

> When value in textbox changes it calls the fr15length() function and is bind with a textbox.

Comment: `ng_value= "@Request['r10length']"` in the first one should be `ng_value= Request["r10length"]`

Comment: Inspect the Html that is generated in the browser to see what is different.

Comment: Changed to as you said, @Request["val"],  retaining value for a second and again losing it after the page complete load

Comment: Changed to as you said, @Request["val"],  retaining value for a second and again disappears after the page complete load. And if the page is refreshed, again appears for a split second and disappears

Comment: This behaviour happens once the angularjs scripts are run to update the values. most likely the `ng-model` tag is causing the issue.

Comment: Try temporarily removing the `ng-model` tag and see if it now holds its value.

Comment: `ng-change` is used to call a function to calculate, when the model changes. If I remove the `ng-model` the calculation will not happen

Comment: _Error_ : Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!

Comment: Retains 3 values when `reset` button is used. It resets the model, as `$scope.conf={}`, then few values are shown but are not binded with the view.

Comment: I was suggesting to *temporarily* remove `ng-model` in order to test this, yes you will have to remove `ng-change` as well. This is just to confirm the cause of the problem, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextBoxFor.It's works fine.

> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.R10Length, new { @class =
>   "form-control fcus", step = "any", min = "1", ng_model =
>   "conf.amr10length", ng_change = "fr15length()", ng_value =
>   "@Request['r10length']" })

Comment: How did it worked, you made mistake in @Request["r10Length"]

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-value` directive is used for setting the value of an element with an `AngularJS` expression.

If you just want to set the value with razor code use the `value` tag:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.R10Length, new { @class="form-control fcus", step="any", min="1", ng_model= "conf.amr10length", ng_change= "fr15length()", value=Request["r10length"] })
```

Note that the value will be lost if in your controller you set `$scope.conf.amr10length` to anything as you've bound that element with `ng-model`.